# Як назвати текст, що продає?

Tags: переклад, вживання-слів

Наскільки я знаю, не властиво для української вживати активні дієприкметники із суфіксом -уч-, тобто "продаючий текст" взагалі не варіант. Норма пропонує "текст, що продає", але це дуже ускладнює речення саме в цьому випадку. Як варіант є словосполучення "комерційний текст", але комерційними може бути багато видів тексту, то що ж робити саме з усталеним поняттям в сфері реклами й копірайтингу?

Comment: Що таке «текст, що продає», чим воно відрізняється від «рекламного тексту» (мається на увазі «ефективний рекламний текст»)? Чи є це терміном? Бо для людини «не в темі», якщо чесно, це словосполучення виглядає просто buzzword'ом.

Comment: Як щодо *продавальний текст*? Тобто текст призначений для того, щоб продавати. Порівняйте з *комунальні служби* - служби призначені для того, щоб виконувати роботи для комуни/міста.

Answer (score 1):

"Ускладнює речення" - це досить суб’єктивне твердження.

Така форма дуже орґанічно вплітається в речення в сучасній українській мові.

Бачимо це на прикладі перекладів назв фільмів на кшталт:

- [Той, хто біжить по лезу.](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%B9,_%D1%85%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83)
- [ТойХтоПройшовКрізьВогонь.](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%A5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8C)
- [Той, що біжить лабіринтом.](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%B9,_%D1%89%D0%BE_%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%96%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC_(%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC))

Є навіть театральна вистава:

- [Той, хто платить.](http://dramteatr.if.ua/content&content_id=771)

Тепер, коли ми розібралися, що така форма вже досить поширена в українському інформаційному полі, просто перевіримо, чи є фраза "текст, що продає" вживаною:

Ґуґлимо "[текст, що продає](https://www.google.com.ua/search?ei=6kiYWv2yNsfWwALNyLjYDA&q=%22%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%20%D1%89%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%94%22&oq=%22%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%20%D1%89%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%94%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...22677.23818.0.24215.2.2.0.0.0.0.134.235.0j2.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.tSX5PxPx5kY)" з лапками, щоби шукало саме цю фразу, і бачимо 1100 результатів. Тобто, маємо геть орґанічну фразу і можемо нею спокійно користуватися.

Comment: 1100 результатів - це швидка приблизна оцінка. Якщо проклацати усі сторінки, то на останній, 38-й сторінці буде написано "Сторінка 38 з такої приблизної кількості результатів: 375 (0,76 сек.)".

Comment: "Ускладнює речення" - це досить суб’єктивне твердження. - та ні, це синтаксично робить підрядну частину, тобто буквально ускладнює.